# Hibernate Query Language in grails

Tags: grails, hql

I am currently working on a grails project where I need to execute a hibernate query. Everytime I run my code with existing data on my database, everything works fine. But if I run it with my database empty, I got an error thrown.

This is my code:

```
    def actActivation = AuditLog.executeQuery("select ll.username from AuditLog ll where ll.event = ? ",[AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION])
    def actDeleted = AuditLog.executeQuery("select ll.username from AuditLog ll where ll.event = ? ",[AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_DELETION])
    def actPurged = AuditLog.executeQuery("select ll.username from AuditLog ll where ll.event = ? ",[AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_PURGING])
    def list = AuditLog.executeQuery("""select sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in(:actActivation)) or (l.username in(:actDeleted) or l.username in(:actPurged))) then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in(:actActivation)) or (l.username in(:actDeleted) or l.username in(:actPurged))) then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in(:actActivation)) or (l.username in(:actDeleted) or l.username in(:actPurged))) then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end),
            sum(case when  l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end)                
        from AuditLog l
        where l.dateCreated >= :startDate and l.dateCreated < :endDate""",
        [
            actActivationEvent:AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
            actDeletionEvent:AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_DELETION,
            actPurgedEvent:AuditLogEvent.ACCOUNT_PURGING,
            actFinishRegEvent:AuditLogEvent.FINISH_REGISTRATION,
            actActivation:actActivation,
            actDeleted:actDeleted,
            actPurged:actPurged, 
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate:endDate
        ])
```

This is the error message when I execute the code with the database empty.

> Class: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException
>
> Message:
>
> unexpected end of subtree [select sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.event = :actActivationEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in()) or (l.username in() or l.username in())) then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in()) or (l.username in() or l.username in())) then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.event = :actFinishRegEvent and ((l.username not in()) or (l.username in() or l.username in())) then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.event = :actDeletionEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Male.%' and l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.details like '%Gender: Female.%' and l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end), sum(case when l.event = :actPurgedEvent then 1 else 0 end) from ph.gov.csc.comex.log.AuditLog l where l.dateCreated >= :startDate and l.dateCreated < :endDate]

How will I resolve this? Help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you blindly pass the result of the three first queries as arguments to the last query. This results in a where clause containing:

```
where ... l.username not in () ...
```

which is invalid. An `in ()` clause must at least have one element inside the parentheses. You should use another query if one of the list you pass as argument to the `in` clauses is empty.